# How to improve button turn on/off experience

Tags: arduino-nano

I have simple circuit turning lights on and off on button click.
It is working quite fine but there is a small issue with button click itself, it is not fully reliable.
Turning lights on is pretty fine but turning them off is tricky.
Basically clicking once almost never works. I need to click in the right moment to turn them off or better keep pressing the button until right moment. If I hold too long it also doesn't work or work wrongly.
Here is the loop code:

```
void loop() {
    int buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
    if (buttonState == 1) active = not active;

    if (active) {
      
       ... led setup

      FastLED.show();
      FastLED.delay(1000 / UPDATES_PER_SECOND);
    } else {
      fill_solid( leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB::Black);
      FastLED.show();
//      FastLED.clear();
    }  
}
```

What do I need to do to make it working as expected which is:

- single click turn light on
- another click or hold for a while turns light off for good and they stay off until next click

Comment: use the Bounce2 library

Comment: It's called "Debouncing" - I think there is even library for it.

Comment: I second Juraj. The Bounce2 library handles this very good

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a couple of things going on here. Debouncing has already been mentioned and I don’t want to discount that at all – there is a ton of information on that subject.

In your case, I think it would be helpful for you to consider 1) how you are defining a button press and 2) how much processing you are doing when you are not checking for a button press.

[image: switch configuration]

To demonstrate, I used this simple set up with a switch:

Then I modified an example from the FastLED library to simply toggle one LED (from a 12 LED, generic, neopixel ring [no clock] and ran it on an UNO (I know you are using a nano, but I think it should still work) using this code.

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 1

int LEDon = 0;
#define DATA_PIN 6

int switchPin = 8;

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  // ## Clockless types ##
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);  // GRB ordering is assumed
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
  // start with LED off (not strictly needed)
  leds[0] = CRGB::Black;
  FastLED.show();
}

void loop() {
  if ( digitalRead(switchPin) == HIGH) { // switch is pressed
    if (LEDon == 0) {
      LEDon = 1;
      leds[0] = CRGB::Red;
      FastLED.show();
    }
    else {
      LEDon = 0;
      leds[0] = CRGB::Black;
      FastLED.show();
    }
    while (digitalRead(switchPin) == HIGH); // wait until switch is released
  }
}
```

I don’t have much experience with this library (it does appear to be very powerful) and don’t know if you can read the state (on/off/color/intensity) of the LEDS – so I just kludged a variable (LEDon) for the example. It works fine. No missed presses and you have to release the button before you can press it again.

Note that I am doing only the minimum amount needed in between looking for a button press.

Libraries are great, but you need to understand a good deal about using them. I think that you are doing time-consuming processing that is causing you to miss presses, which is why you say “*I need to click in the right moment to turn them off or better keep pressing the button until right moment*”.

I also think that you are ill-defining a press. In the code, I am specifically looking for the button to be released. Because some time is spent processing after the button press is detected, I don’t have to explicitly debounce the switch – for this example. That does not mean that you can always get away with that.

Think about how functionally vague your definition of a press is,
*•  single click turn light on
•   another click or hold for a while turns light off for good and they stay off until next click*

I would respectfully recommend that you:

Learn as much as you can about the library. Take a look, for example, at this discussion FastLED.delay()  https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/issues/1206

Do as much as you possibly can in setup().

Do as little as you need to in-between checking for a press (or think about using interrupt).

Hope it helps.